# C Pipe between a parent and 2 children

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, fork, posix

I can not figure out why only 1 child sends data to parent (only the 1st child).. 
When I do sleep(5) after the child1 sends data through pipe to parent then the 2nd child sends the same prime number to the parent.

Can someone help me?

```js
//--------------------------Consts---------------------------------
#define NUM_OF_CHILDS 2
#define N 20
#define WIN 5

struct msg{
 pid_t _pid;
 int _prime;
};

//--------------------------Prototypes-----------------------------
bool is_prime(int num);
void terminate(pid_t child_pid[],int fd[2]);
void do_child(int fd[2]);
void print_pair(const int f_arr[],const int s_arr[]);

//--------------------------Main-------------------------------------
int main()
{
 int f_arr[N] = {0},
  s_arr[N] = {0},
  ind, //running on children fork
  count1 = 0,
  count2 = 0,
  victory1 = 0,
  victory2 = 0,
  min = 0;

 int fd[2];

 bool read1 = false,
  read2 = false;

 srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
 pid_t child_pid [NUM_OF_CHILDS];//children pid status array

 struct msg msg1;

 if (pipe(fd) == -1)//pipe fd
 {
  perror("cannot open pipe");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 for(ind = 0; ind < NUM_OF_CHILDS; ind++)
 {
  child_pid[ind] = fork();// duplicate the current process

  if (child_pid[ind] < 0)//fork failed
  {
   perror("Cannot fork()");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if(child_pid[ind] == 0)/* child : sends message to parent*/
   do_child(fd);
 }

 /* parent : receives message from child */
 close(fd[1]); // close the write-end of the pipe

 //read data from pipe
 while(read(fd[0],&msg1,sizeof(struct msg)) > 0)
 {
  if(child_pid[0] == msg1._pid)
  {
   f_arr[count1++] = msg1._prime;
   read1 = true;
  }

  else
  {
   s_arr[count2++] = msg1._prime;
   read2 = true;
  }

  if(read1 && read2)
  {
   if(f_arr[min] > s_arr[min])
    victory1++;
   else if(f_arr[min] < s_arr[min])
    victory2++;

   read1 = false;
   read2 = false;
   min++;
  }

  if(victory1 == WIN || victory2 == WIN)
   terminate(child_pid,fd);
 }

 close(fd[0]);// close the read-end of the pipe
 print_pair(f_arr,s_arr);

 return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//checking if number is a prime number or not
//and return true or false
bool is_prime(int num)
{
 int i;
 if(num==0 || num==1 || num==2)
  return false;
 for(i=2;i<=num/2;i++)
 {
  //the number is not prime
  if(num%i == 0)
   return false;
 }
 //the number is prime
 return true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
void do_child(int fd[2])
{
 struct msg message;
 int num;

 close(fd[0]);

 while (1)
 {
  num = rand() % 1000;
  if(is_prime(num))
  {
   message._prime = num;
   message._pid = getpid();
   write(fd[1], &message, sizeof(struct msg));
  }
 }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
void terminate(pid_t child_pid[],int fd[2])
{
 int ind,
 loop;

 for(ind = 0; ind < NUM_OF_CHILDS; ind++)
 {
  close(fd[1]);
  //first to give the process an opportunity to die gratefully before
  //using SIGKILL
  kill(child_pid[ind], SIGTERM);
  bool died = false;
  //It will give the process 5 seconds to die gracefully
  for (loop = 0; loop < 5 && !died; ++loop)
  {
   int pid;
   //the time the child process takes to close down gracefully.
   sleep(1);
   //to get the return status of that process and prevent zombie processes.
   if (waitpid(child_pid[ind], &pid, WNOHANG) == child_pid[ind])
    died = true;
  }
  //if SIGTERM did not killed the child do SIGKILL
  if (!died)
  {
   int pid;
   kill(child_pid[ind], SIGKILL);
   waitpid(child_pid[ind], &pid, 0);// harvest the zombie
  }

 }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
void print_pair(const int f_arr[],const int s_arr[])
{
 int ind;
 for(ind = 0; ind < N; ind++)
 {
  if(f_arr[ind] == 0 && s_arr[ind] == 0)
   break;
  printf("(%d,%d)\n",f_arr[ind],s_arr[ind]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the two child processes are generating the same pseudorandom sequence because they're starting with the same seed. To have any chance of different numbers, you need to seed them after the fork, and probably use something that changes more than once per second (the chance of the two of them having different values of `time()` is very small even if you moved the `srand(time(NULL))` after the fork).

Second, you are receiving all the numbers from the first process because it has a head start. There's plenty of time to write to the pipe while the second process is being created. The parent doesn't start reading until after both children are created, so the first child fills the pipe buffer and then blocks. Pipe buffers are at least a few kilobytes.

Even when I slowed down the child process by making it print the numbers to stderr, the first one still generated hundreds of numbers before the second one got going.

So what happens in your main loop when there are hundreds of messages arriving from child 1 and none from child 2? Your `f_arr` array overflows because it only has room for 20. After that, anything can happen.

The simplest way to prevent that would be to check whether `count1 == N` before attempting to store a number into `f_arr[count1++]`, and if so, just `continue;` to the next message. You should do the same for messages from the second child, even though it's not likely to happen.

This way you'll be accepting at most `N` messages from each child, and ignoring the rest. You'll need to add another end condition to the main loop: if both children have sent `N` messages, you need to stop.

Another way to go would be to use a separate pipe for each child and alternate reading from both pipes to keep them synchronized, but I have a feeling you were deliberately avoiding that.

Comment: "but I have a feeling you were deliberately avoiding that "- you are correct. Tnx for your comment!